# How exlude properties when building executable jar in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jar, executable, properties-file

This question has been covered here before, but the only solutions I could find were in relation to a project using Ant or Maven. I am using neither. Here is the situation:

I have some application parameters in a properties file. This file is located in my Eclipse project (but in the src folder) and used when I run the application from Eclipse. In addition, I would like the application to also run as an executable jar file, in which case the user can provide the name of a properties file to use in a command line parameters.

The problem now is that the properties file from the project is always packaged into the executable jar and therefore the user is not able to easily modify the properties (yes, I know that (s)he could unzip the jar, but I want to avoid the extra steps).

How can I prevent the properties from being packages into the executable jar file?

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: How do you build? Through Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Create a executable jar without properties file in it. Place both jar and properties file in a folder. Now add little code in your main program which should look for a properties file in the same folder and get the complete path of it. And then you can do something like this

```
System.getProperties().load(new FileInputStream(completepath));
```

So now your properties will be loaded into system properties with out affecting the actual system properties. You can access your properties by `System.getProperty("Propertyname");`

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Hi Sri777, thanks a lot for the reply. This has worked fine. I have not been able to fully exclude the existing properties file from the executable JAR, but this doesn't matter, because they can be overriden give your solution.

Comment: Just to note, the base path for the running JAR can be optained using this: (new File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath())).getAbsolutePath();